# Blacklist Shipping Address Logic

Tags: .net, sql, security, logic

I need some ideas for the logic behind a project I want to implement.  Basically we have been having a problem with a few (under 10) "customers" using fraudulent credit cards.  What happens is they use the credit card, (which is valid) to buy items and have them shipped to them.  Then, the real card owner sees what was bought on their statement and disputes it leaving us to cover the cost of the goods we shipped.  The "customer" in question uses different email addresses and different accounts everytime so its impossible for me to block his account.  But he does use the same shipping address.  So I was thinking maybe that was the best way to block him.  Do you think the easiest way would be to create a table in the database with addresses we know are being used for fraudulent orders and cross check the address on every submit order.  Or would there be an easier way to do this.  We already verify credit cards upon entry but like i said before the cards are still valid-they aren't being reported as stolen.

Comment: What RDBMS? In SQL Server it would be super easy.  Also as an aside, if you know the criminal's shipping address, can't you share that with the proper authorities?

Comment: we have. nothing has been done.

Answer (score 7):

I think the first thing you need to do is call the police and have them arrested for fraud.  That should clear up the issue with them for 3-5 years.

Otherwise, if the addresses are exactly the same then, yes you could do a string match.

**UPDATE**:
If you want to put a lot of programmer and infrastructure time and money in on it, I'd go with Abe Miessler's answer about lat and long.  If you want a quick and dirty way, go with a straight address match by breaking out city state and zip.  Then you can compare the street addresses

`where zipcode=zipcode`

Comment: `you could do a string match.` They would probably get around that in about 2.5 seconds.  111 First St., 111 1st St, 111 1st street, 111 first street, etc...

Comment: @Abe Miessler yeah, but I'm hoping they haven't figured that out yet that it might save them a few bucks till the cops show up.

Comment: Definitely this. Simply blocking his address will only stop the criminal from abusing _your_ site, but does not help other websites or the people who had their cards stolen. And if he's willing to do this kind of fraud, he might simply tweak his address (e.g. "Apartment 123" -> "#123") or just ship to the address of a friend/family member. Do the right thing: report this person (with their address) to the police and to the credit card companies ASAP.

Comment: While good advice, and it's also good advice for OP should work with the authorities to support the investigation, it's possible that the authorities can't do anything, such as crimes committed overseas.  Or that they won't do anything, like crimes for very low dollar amounts committed overseas.  In such a case, the OP may have to protect him/herself.

Comment: ok for everyone that is saying contact the authroities.  we have.  we gave them the information we have.  Im not sure what they are doing.  It isnt really my area. I know that the dud placed another order 2 days ago.  As far as I know that information has been passed along too.  This isnt the question I was asking.

Comment: @Tking ~ So you should specify that in the beginning. Otherwise, see Abe's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that a good way to block black listed addresses might be to geocode the evil address (distill it to it's lat long using Google mapping API or something) and then geocode all incoming addresses and compare to the black list of lat/longs.

Google seems to do a pretty good job at taking different variations of the same address and returning the same lat/long.  Just a thought.

**UPDATE**

also you should DEFINITELY alert the authorities.  Might even be able to get some money out of this schmo

Comment: That's pretty ingenious. Still doesn't get around the moral obligation to send in SWAT. Especially when it's the cheaper economic option (the thief IS costing this guy's company money)